# Erro função de enviar e-mail

Tags: delphi

Estou com o seguinte codigo para mandar um email no delphi, mas ele da um erro (em anexo) no final do codigo após o ultimo end.
Estou usando a versão mais recente do delphi e ele me informa se os begins, try ends estão fechados.
O que pode causar isso?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  // variáveis e objetos necessários para o envio
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage: TIdMessage;
  IdText: TIdText;
  sAnexo: string;
begin
  // instanciação dos objetos
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(Self);
  IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(Self);

  try
    // Configuração do protocolo SSL (TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL)
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;

    // Configuração do servidor SMTP (TIdSMTP)
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Port := 465;
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Username := 'usuario@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'senha';

    // Configuração da mensagem (TIdMessage)
    IdMessage.From.Address := 'remetente@gmail.com';
    IdMessage.From.Name := 'Nome do Remetente';
    IdMessage.ReplyTo.EMailAddresses := IdMessage.From.Address;
    IdMessage.Recipients.Add.Text := 'destinatario1@email.com';
    IdMessage.Subject := 'Assunto do e-mail';
    IdMessage.Encoding := meMIME;

    // Configuração do corpo do email (TIdText)
    IdText := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts);
    IdText.Body.Add('Corpo do e-mail');
    IdText.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1';

    // Opcional - Anexo da mensagem (TIdAttachmentFile)
    sAnexo := 'C:\Anexo.pdf';
    if FileExists(sAnexo) then
    begin
      TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, sAnexo);
    end;

    // Conexão e autenticação
    try
      IdSMTP.Connect;
      IdSMTP.Authenticate;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Erro na conexão ou autenticação: ' +
          E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    // Envio da mensagem
    try
      IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      MessageDlg('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
    except
      On E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Erro ao enviar a mensagem: ' +
          E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    // desconecta do servidor
    IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    // liberação da DLL
    UnLoadOpenSSLLibrary;
    // liberação dos objetos da memória
    FreeAndNil(IdMessage);
    FreeAndNil(IdSSLIOHandlerSocket);
    FreeAndNil(IdSMTP);
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como estão as clausulas Uses de sua Unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clique após o `end.` e Pressione simultaneamente as teclas CRTL+SHIT+T e pressione a tecla DELETE.

Segure CTRL e aperte 9 e veja se deu algo!

`\win32\Debug\unit1.DCU`

Remove essa unit `unit1` do projeto (Project -> Remove from project) e adiciona novamente(Project -> Add to project).

A IDE não conseguiu criar este arquivo que faz parte de seu projeto (Se estiver usando Windows 8(ou superior), verifique as permissões de Pasta de onde o seu projeto esta sendo Compilado!), acesse a pasta e crie manualmente o arquivo mencionado!

Comment: A solução foi remover a unit e adiconar.